# Change React-Native TextInput's placeholder color

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an Android app using React Native in which there's a form. The placeholder doesn't even appear for the textInput fields so I thought of changing the placeholder color but I don't know how to do that. The docs mentioned some way which I don't understand.

Here's the code:

```
  <TextInput
  secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
  style={inputStyle}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  />

  inputStyle: {
  color: '#000',
  paddingRight: 5,
  paddingLeft: 5,
  fontSize: 18,
  lineHeight: 23,
  flex: 2,
  }
```

I also tried:

```
  <TextInput
  placeholderTextColor="blue"
  style={inputStyle}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  />
```

and

```
  inputStyle: {
  color: '#000',
  paddingRight: 5,
  paddingLeft: 5,
  fontSize: 18,
  lineHeight: 23,
  flex: 2,
  placeholderTextColor: '#333'
  }
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Like so:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder="something"
   placeholderTextColor="#000" 
/>
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the `placeholderTextColor` prop to change the color of the placeholder text.

For example:

```
<TextInput placeholder="First name..." placeholderTextColor="#FFF" />
```

You can check the [React Native TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) reference for this and more options on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `placeholderTextColor` prop of TextInput component. Check it out here https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Answer (score 0):

Try using `placeholderTextColor` property to maintain placeholder color.
`secureTextEntry` props are generally used for password input.
It's best to follow official document. I think they described everything in a proper way.